# Why does the water at the same temperature on the same vessel with water having less mass cool faster?

Tags: temperature, water, popular-science, cooling

10 litres of water at 80-degree Celsius cools faster than 15 litres of water at the same temperature kept in identical vessel, why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the substance and temperature is same so heat capacity is same. Also, as temperature is same and surrounding is same, so initially temperauture gradient is same. Therefore amount of heat dissipiation depends upon mass or volume of matter. Initially rate of heat dissipiation is same because entropy of surrounding and system is same and temperature is same. Now amount of heat dissipate if $q_1=q_2$ initially, $$q_1=m_1c\Delta T_1,\ \text{and,}\ q_2=m_2c\Delta T_2$$ On dividing first by second,$$m_1\Delta T_1=m_2\Delta T_2\Rightarrow \frac{m_1}{m_2}=\frac{\Delta T_2}{\Delta T_1}$$Now if, $m_1\gt m_2\ $ then, $\ \Delta T_2\gt\Delta T_1\ $ which means change in temperature of lighter mass is more. Also as more mass can absorb more heat at same temoerature, thus require more time to cool down.

Cooling depends upon designing also. A volume consisting of thin layer and more exposing area tends to cool quicker and may be faster than lesser mass of same substance, this is included in emissitivity or absorpivity. So ration of surface area to volume is also factor. More the ratio, faster the cooling.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer.**
In general this is not true, as you can see if you reach the end of the answer.

The main parameters that govern the rate of change of the temperature of a system are:

- the mass (not the density), since with more mass you have more matter to cool down,
- the heat transfer to the system, that it's influenced by both the physical properties of the system and its geometric shape.

**Some details, starting from the first principle of thermodynamics.**
The answer comes from the first principle of thermodynamics,

$\dot{E} = P^{ext} + \dot{Q}^{ext}$,

namely the variation of the energy of a system equals the power of the external forces acting on it and the heat flux with the external environment. Assuming we're doing no work on the system, and thus $P^{ext} = 0$, the first principle of thermodynamics reduces to

$\dot{E} = \dot{Q}^{ext}$.

Now, total internal energy of a system in equilibrium, under some assumptions, can be reasonably written as $E = m C \Delta T$, being

- $m$ the total mass of the system, constant in classical mechanics for a closed system;
- $c$ its specific heat capacity, assumed to constant;
- and $T$ its temperature;

so that we can write the first principle equation for the two systems of mass $m_1$ and $m_2$, assuming they have the same heat capacity

$m_1 c \ \dot{T}_1 = \dot{Q}_1 \qquad , \qquad m_2 c \ \dot{T}_2 = \dot{Q}_2$

and taking the ratio we get

$\dfrac{ \dot{T}_1}{ \dot{T}_2} = \dfrac{m_2}{m_1}\dfrac{\dot{Q}_1}{\dot{Q}_2} $,

i.e. the ratio of change of the system temperature (time derivative) is:

- directly proportional to the ration of heat flux exchanged with the external environment
- inversely proportional to the ratio of mass.

Some examples follow.

**1. Equal heat flux.** If the heat fluxes are the same $\dot{Q}_1 = \dot{Q}_2$, the ratio of time derivative of the temperature of the system is inversely proportional to the ratio of their masses

$\dfrac{ \dot{T}_1}{ \dot{T}_2} = \dfrac{m_2}{m_1}$.

Moreover, if the heat flux is constant $\dot{Q}$ in time, in an interval of time $\Delta t$, you get

$\Delta T_i = \dfrac{Q\Delta t}{m_i c} $.

**2. Total heat flux proportional to the outer surface of the fluid volume.** If the total heat flux is the sum of the elementary contributions due to heat exchange through all of its parts, heat flux is proportional to the surface of the fluid volume. If we call $k(T, \text{params})$ this constant of proportionality, s.t. $\dot{Q} = k(T, \text{params}) S$, and we assume that we're looking at the temperature ratio starting from the same temperature, so that we can write $k(T_1, \text{params}_1) = k(T_2, \text{params}_2) = k$, we get

$\dfrac{ \dot{T}_1}{ \dot{T}_2} = \dfrac{m_2}{m_1}\dfrac{\dot{Q}_1}{\dot{Q}_2} =\dfrac{\rho_2 V_2}{\rho_1 V_1}\dfrac{k S_1}{k S_2} $

and assuming that water has approximately constant density $\rho_1 = \rho_2 = \rho$, we get

$\dfrac{ \dot{T}_1}{ \dot{T}_2} =\dfrac{V_2}{V_1}\dfrac{S_1}{S_2}$,

we found out that the ratio of the time derivative of the system temperature (assuming the temperature homogeneous in the whole system, quite a strong assumption) is inversely proportional to the volume of the system and directly proportional to its external surface.

So in general, its not true that the a system changes temperature in a way that is proportional to its mass. You can see it from the last equation, and you can easily realize looking at a radiator (that is plenty of fins, to increase the ratio $S/V$, proportional to the temperature derivative) or when you spread hot rice in a dish (to increase $S/V$, as well).

Anyway, if the liquid is in the same vessel with conducting walls, and the walls are orthogonal to the base surface, the volume occupied by the liquid is $V_i= S h_i$ and thus

$\dfrac{ \dot{T}_1}{ \dot{T}_2} =\dfrac{V_2}{V_1} = \dfrac{h_2}{h_1} = \dfrac{m_2}{m_1}$

Comment: Instead of writing in terms of height, it is better if you write it in terms of ratio of surface area by volume. More the ratio, more quickly it absorb or emit heat and this relates to heat radiation of a body.